# ZF3 dbadapters not getting in form validation

Tags: validation, zend-framework, adapter, zend-framework3

I have configure dbadapters as per below.

Added below code in config/autoload/global.php

```
  use Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage;
  use Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr;
  use Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent;

  use Zend\Db\Adapter;
  use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;


   return [
// Session configuration.
'session_config' => [
    'cookie_lifetime' => 60 * 60 * 1, // Session cookie will expire in 1 hour.
    'gc_maxlifetime' => 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // How long to store session data on server (for 1 month).        
],
// Session manager configuration.
'session_manager' => [
    // Session validators (used for security).
    'validators' => [
        RemoteAddr::class,
        HttpUserAgent::class,
    ]
],
// Session storage configuration.
'session_storage' => [
    'type' => SessionArrayStorage::class
],

'service_manager' => [
    'abstract_factories' => [
        Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory::class,
    ],
    'factories' => [
        Adapter\AdapterInterface::class => Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory::class,
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        Adapter\Adapter::class => Adapter\AdapterInterface::class,
    ],  
],

];
```

After that i have added below code to config/autoload/development.local.php

```
return [
'view_manager' => [
    'display_exceptions' => true,
],

'doctrine' => [
    'connection' => [
        'orm_default' => [
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'params' => [
                'host' => 'host',
                'user' => 'root',
                'password' => 'root',
                'dbname' => 'dbname',
            ]
        ],
    ],
],

'db' => [
    'adapters' => [
        'db' => [
            'driver' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=host',
            'driver_options' => [
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
            ],
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
        ],
    ],
],
];
```

How to get dbAdapters in controller and form?

I want to use **NoRecordExists** validation in form filter.
like

```
  array(
                    'name' => 'Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists',
                    'options' => array(
                        'table' => 'test_user',
                        'field' => 'email',
                        'adapter' => $this->dbAdapter,
                        'exclude' => $this->excludeFields,
                        'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND => 'Email already exists'
                        ),
                    ),
                    'break_chain_on_failure' => true
                )
```

Share your ideas or give me suggestion to configure dbAdapters globally in ZF3.

Comment: Have you tried following the zend documentation? https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/#database-and-models

Comment: And are you trying to use doctrine or zend-db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the adapter into the form using a factory. I'm not sure if form validation with Doctrine is supported out of the box so my example will be using regular old zend-db.

## In short:

Set up a simple factory and supply the adapter to the form using dependency injection.

### The form

The form needs to accept the dependency, so add a parameter to the constructor:

```
/**
 * @var \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter
 */
private $dbAdapter;

/**
 * @param \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter $adapter
 */
public function __construct(\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter $adapter)
{
    $this->dbAdapter = $adapter;
}
```

### The factory

```
namespace MyModule\Factory\Form;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

/**
 * Class MyFormFactory
 * @package MyModule\Factory\Form
 */
class MyFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create an object
     *
     * @param  ContainerInterface $container
     * @param  string             $requestedName
     * @param  null|array         $options
     *
     * @return object
     * @throws ServiceNotFoundException if unable to resolve the service.
     * @throws ServiceNotCreatedException if an exception is raised when
     *     creating a service.
     * @throws ContainerException if any other error occurs
     */
    public function __invoke(
        ContainerInterface $container,
        $requestedName,
        array $options = null
    ) {
        /** @var \Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface $adapter */
        $adapter  = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);

        return new MyForm($adapter);
    }
}
```

### Finally:

In your module.config.php you need to tell your application to invoke the factory to set up the form:

```
'service_manager_' => [
    'factories' => [
        Form\MyForm::class => Factory\Form\MyFormFactory::class
    ]
],
```

As [Dymen1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3784145/dymen1) mentioned you could probably benefit from trying out the [tutorial in the documentation](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/#database-and-models) where this subject is explained.